# Ionic & AngularJS: Variable in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic (and stackoverflow ;-) ), but my app is nearly finished expect one little thing, where i need your help!

I have a Detail View (produktDetail.html) in which I have to put an ion-slide-box. This slide-box should include an ng-rpeat, e.g:

```
<ion-slide ng-repeat="steps in Clicker"></ion-slide>
```

This works fine. But I have to replace "Clicker" with a dynamic Variable, wich I pass together with the Detail View. When I put

```
{{produkt.cards_name}}
```

into the template, it works finde and I see the word "Clicker". but when I replace "Clicker" in the ion-slide with it, I can't see anything. How can I fix it?

Here is some Code.

(Controller.js)

```
.controller('BrowseCtrl', function($scope, ProduktService){
$scope.productList = ProduktService.getAll();

})

.controller('ProduktDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, ProduktService){

    var produktId = $stateParams.produktName;
    $scope.produkt = ProduktService.getSelected(produktId);

      $scope.Clicker = [
    { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Lulu', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Blabla', id: 1 }
    ];

})

.controller('CoachCtrl', function(){

})
;
```

(App.js)

```
.factory('ProduktService', function(){

    var productList = [

        {name: "Der Clicker",
         txt: "Das Training mit dem Clicker ist eine einfache, aber sehr effektive Methode des Hundetrainings. Über die Funktionsweise des Clickers erfährst du hier mehr.",
         img_pre: "../www/img/kurse/preview/Clicker_pre.jpg",
         img_de: "../www/img/kurse/detail/Clicker.png", 
         cards_name: "Clicker",
         trailer: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/kPsrI0cW1EQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0",
         be1: "10",
         be2: "5",
         be3: "2",
        },

        {name: "Das Platz",
         txt: "Neben 'Sitz' ist Platz eines der Signale, dass du deinem Hund am häufigsten geben wirst. Somit ist 'Platz' eine absolute Basic Übung.",
         img_pre: "../www/img/kurse/preview/platz_pre.jpg",
         img_de: "../www/img/kurse/detail/Platz.jpg",
         cards_name: 'Platz',
         trailer: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/kTcbNF3Bq14?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0",
         be1: "7",
         be2: "3",
         be3: "2",
        },

        {name: "Das Sitz",
         txt: "Gemeinsam mit dem Signal 'Platz' ist 'Sitz' eines der Signale, dass du deinem Hund am häufigsten geben wirst. Damit ist auch dieses Signal eine absolute Basic Übung.",
         img_pre: "../www/img/kurse/preview/sitz_pre.jpg",
         img_de: "../www/img/kurse/detail/Sitz.jpg",
         cards_name: 'Sitz',
         trailer: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/VRKlvi2F-y0?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0",
         be1: "7",
         be2: "3",
         be3: "2",
},
    ];

    var treffer;

    return{
        getAll: function(){
            return productList;
        },
        getSelected: function(produkt_name){
            productList.forEach(function(object){
                if(angular.equals(object.name, produkt_name)){
                    treffer = object;
                }
            })
            return treffer;
        }
    }
})
```

(Browse.html - Master View)

```
<ion-view view-title="Kurse">
  <ion-content>

      <ion-list>

          <ion-item class="item item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="produkt in productList" ng-href="#/app/browse/{{produkt.name}}">
            <img src="{{produkt.img_pre}}" id="img_preview">
            <h2>{{produkt.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{produkt.txt}}</p>
            <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <br>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And last: produktDetail.html (Detail View)

```
<ion-view view-title="{{produkt.name}}">

  <ion-content>

      <div class="responsive-video">
<iframe src="{{produkt.trailer}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>          
      <p class="desc">{{produkt.txt}}</p>
      <br>

<ion-slide-box show-pager="false">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="steps in Clicker">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            <h2>{{steps.title}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">

        </div>    
    </div>

  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Hope you understand what I meant - Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Decent question, might want to show a bit more code to show what is going on.

Comment: `ng-repeat="steps in something[product.cards_name]"`

Comment: Sure. I've put it in the question above!

Comment: `produkt.cards_name` isn't an array or an object. What do you expect if you write `steps in produkt.cards_name`?

Answer (score 0):

{{...}} for expressions(strings or numbers) only. object will be converted to string. 
try change value of variable Clicker, rather than variable itself. or 
$scope.Clicker = {ret:[...],ter:[...]} and in html: ng-repeat="steps in Clicker [product.cards_name]"